# Error sending email via nodemailer via office365 on google app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm running a node application where I'm able to send mail through nodemailer fine when running the app locally but when I deploy it to Google Cloud (node on flexible instance) I get a **timeout**. I've tried several transport configurations, the latest being an office365 account. They all run fine locally but when running on google cloud I get a timeout. Is this a constraint when running on Google Cloud?

**Update** - Never mind, I found this on Google Cloud Docs,

"Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. By default, these outbound SMTP ports are blocked because of the large amount of abuse these ports are susceptible to. In addition, having a trusted third-party provider such as SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet relieves Compute Engine and you from maintaining IP reputation with your receivers."

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm from Mailjet.

Indeed, as said by the Google Cloud docs, SMTP ports are blocked because spammers usually spawn a lot of cheap instances to send their fraudulent emails. They're not the only one to do it; Azure also blocks these ports.

As you may know, Internet Service Providers fight a lot against spam, and they are very prone to ban suspicious IP. To be sure your emails are received in your users' inboxes, you must put yourself in a good light. Using Email Service Providers, such as [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailjet) and the others quoted above, clearly improve deliverability. Because they use good IPs, have a good reputation, throttle emails... If you want to know more about deliverability, don't hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into an issue sending Wordpress email through Office 365 email in the cloud and it may be similar with google cloud. They dont use traditional smtp credentials. You have to have an SPF record on the sending server and send it without authentication. I didnt implement it myself so I cant go into further details. But maybe it'll help someone someday.